# Extension methods for converting IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T> to ReadOnlyCollection<T>

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, extension-methods, ienumerable, iqueryable

How to write extension methods for converting `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` to `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<T> AsReadOnlyCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if(source == null)
      throw new ArgumentNulLException("source");

    IList<T> list = source as IList<T> ?? source.ToList();
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(list);
}
```

Note that there is no such thing as "converting" an `IEnumerable<T>` in this case (as with all other methods in the LINQ stack), you will get back a different object than before.

Comment: `source as IList<T> ?? source.ToList();` ?

Comment: Oh, sure. I usually go around the coalescing operator as I doesn't come naturally to me (not that I don't understand it).

Comment: sorry, forgot the generic type parameter in the method body.

Comment: @Nima, extension methods can be put only in static classes

Comment: @Nima, class itself should be non-generic, only method should be generic.

Comment: Please note that the returned collection behaves differently depending on whether or not the passed `IEnumerable<>` is already an `IList<>`. If it is then any future mutations of that source collection will be reflected in your `ReadOnlyCollection<>`; if not then your `ReadOnlyCollection<>` is effectively immutable. Dangerous construct. Stick to one.

Answer (score 8):

`List<T>` already contains an extension method `AsReadOnly()`, so just do something like:

```
queryable.ToList().AsReadOnly()
```