# Return ReadOnlyCollection from IList<>

Tags: c#, .net, list, ienumerable, readonly-collection

OK, so List<> contains the AsReadOnly() which gives you the ReadOnlyCollection. What I need is to have a field of IList type, and a property which would return a ReadOnlyCollection for this list.

Example class:

```
class Test
{
   private IList<Abc> list;

   public AddToList(Abc someItem) { /* adds inside the list */... }

   public ReadOnlyCollection<Abc> List { get { return ??? } } // <- no "set" here!
}
```

The scenario is following: I need to have some custom logic inside my class when the item is added into the list, and I want to restrict adding to this list by calling AddToList(someitem), while not allowing the usage of list.Add(someItem). The problem is that I use **NHibernate** which **requires the IList interface**, so I cannot cast / call the AsReadOnly() on the IList (it does not contain this method).

What way would you recommend to solve this situation? I simply need a way for NHibernate to set the needed collection in some way, but I also need to restrict users.

Comment: You might also want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522654/extension-methods-for-converting-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet-to-readonlycol

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can just emulate `AsReadOnly()`:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<Abc> List
{
    get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Abc>(list); }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
This doesn't create a copy of `list`. `ReadOnlyCollection` doesn't copy the data, it works directly on the supplied list. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132476.aspx):

> A collection that is read-only is simply a collection with a wrapper that prevents modifying the collection; therefore, if changes are made to the underlying collection, the read-only collection reflects those changes.
>   This constructor is an O(1) operation.

Comment: Will this create a new collection with iteration through all items, or it keeps the reference to the underlying innerCollection ?

Comment: It doesn't create a copy. This is exactly the same code as is used in `AsReadOnly`. If you don't want that behavior, you should rephrase your question.

Answer (score 7):

try

```
return new ReadOnlyCollection<Abc> (list);
```

Comment: OK, I also thought of this, but I would prefer the solution which doesn't copy over the contents of the collection to another collection, and this will do that beneath, right ?

Comment: this will make a copy... a solution without copying is only possible IF you create a class the implements the IList interface and use that...

Comment: @Yahia: Wrong. It doesn't create a copy

Answer (score 1):

Use following way,

```
public class Test
    {

        private IList<SubTest>      _subTests;


        public virtual void AddSubTest(SubTest SubTest)
        {
            if (_subTests == null)
                _subTests = new List<SubTest>();

            _subTests.Add(SubTest);

            return this;
        }


        public virtual IReadOnlyList<SubTest> SubTests
        {
            get
            {
                if (_subTests == null)
                    _subTests = new List<SubTest>();

                return _subTests.AsReadOnly();
            }
        }




        public void RemoveSubTest( SubTest SubTest )
        {
            if( _subTests == null ) 
                return;

            _subTests.Remove( SubTest );            
        }

    }
```

use following mapping, and it would sets the value to the field not to the property which is read only list

```
<bag 
      name="SubTests" table="SubTest" lazy="true" access="field.camelcase-underscore"
      optimistic-lock="false"
      >
      <key column ="TestID" />
      <many-to-many class="SubTest, Domain" column="SubTestID" />
    </bag>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also return `IEnumerable<Abc>` which is read only iterator and provide methods for adding and removing elements.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to do this is to return `IEnumerable<Abc>` using the [method suggested by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491375/readonlycollection-or-ienumerable-for-exposing-member-collections):

```
public IEnumerable<Abc> Abcs {
    get { return list.Skip(0); }
}
```

If you're not worried about consumers casting the `IEnumerable<T>` back to `IList<T>` you can just return `IEnumerable<T>`.

`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` has some serious flaws, the primary one being that it implements `IList<T>` so it does have Add and Remove methods. This can lead to runtime errors if consumers neglect to check its ReadOnly property. I strongly recommend against using it.

Answer (score 0):

As of .NET 7, there's now an extension method available on the `IList` interface that you can use:

`IList.AsReadOnly()`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.asreadonly?view=net-8.0