# How to Convert List<string> to ReadOnlyCollection<string> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, collections

I want to convert the items entered to a String list to:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string>
```

I have tried using:

```
(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string>)listname
```

But it returns an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return ReadOnlyCollection from IList<>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227611/return-readonlycollection-from-ilist)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can create a new instance using the existing List in the constructor.

```
var readOnlyList = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(existingList);
```

[ReadOnlyCollection(Of T) Constructor on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132476.aspx)

Answer (score 46):

If you've got:

`List<string> names=new List<string>(){"Rod", "Jane", "Freddy"};`

Then you can say:

`ReadOnlyCollection<string> readOnlyNames=names.AsReadOnly();`

This doesn't copy the list. Instead the readonly collection stores a reference to the original list and prohibits changing it. However, if you modify the underlying list via `names` then the `readOnlyNames` will also change, so it's best to discard the writable instance if you can.

Answer (score 6):

The constructor of ReadOnlyCollection accepts an IList

Here is some reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132476.aspx

```
var myreadonlycollection = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(listname);
```

Comment: @Errorstacks... Thanks for the downvote.  but you should not plagiarize.

Comment: @Errorstacks....lol its funny I never said you were copying off of me.  But you copied the exact code from MSDN.  Just reference the link and describe.

Answer (score 5):

```
var readonlyCollection = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(list);
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct in that you need to pass an `IList<T>` to the constructor of a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

I find it useful to have an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` that facilitates the creation of the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`:

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<T> ToReadOnlyCollection<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(
        source as IList<T> ?? source.ToList());
}
```

Comment: So your `source.ToReadOnlyCollection()` is pretty much equivalent to the built-in `source.ToList().AsReadOnly()`. (Also, your code behaves differently depending on whether or not the passed-in `IEnumerable<>` is already an `IList<>`. If it is then any future mutations of that source collection will be reflected in your `ReadOnlyCollection<>`; if not then your `ReadOnlyCollection<>` is effectively immutable.)